# Is there a way to forward ONLY spam messages in GMail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

I'm trying to create a filter that would automatically forward only the messages marked as spam to a company that signs you up for class actions against known spammy companies. I haven't found a way to identify only messages that are going to get marked as spam yet though.

Comment: You cannot.  Similar to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/168563/gmail-filter-forward-emails-that-arrive-to-inbox-to-one-email-address-and-emai)

Answer (score 1):

For Gmail end-users there are two ways to forward emails,

1. by forwarding all email
2. by using filters and forwarding only the emails catched by the filter

In this case you should use the second option. As there is no search operator to indentify spam emails at the time that the filter run you should craft your own search criteria to catch those messages. This will be a some sort of learning process, you should start with an initial filter, you might find helpful to set it to add a label, i.e. `spam-fw` to the filtered messages.

- Periodically review Spam and the label assigned to the forwared messages ( i.e. `spam-fw`).
  This should not be done later than every 30 days as Spam is automatically deleted after 30 days.
- Analyse what you found.
- Improve your filter and/or add additional filters.

The alternative might be to use another email service. One option might be Google Workspace which give administrators more options about how the email is handled but also requires to learn more about how email works, among other things.

Related

- [How to send messages to spam in Gmail filter?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/49493/88163)
- [How to get Gmail to forward all mail except from a certain address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/73962/88163)